# Can `tesseract-ocr` put the result to STDOUT?

Tags: tesseract

Using `tesseract-ocr` #3.02.02.

The basic usage of tesseract is

```
tesseract sourc.png result
```

and `result.txt` is generated. To get the result text, I have to cat this file.

Is there any options to dump the result in stdout?

Answer (score 21, accepted):

You should upgrade to v3.03 where [support for stdout was added](https://github.com/tesseract-ocr/tesseract/wiki/ReleaseNotes#tesseract-release-notes-feb-4-2014---v303rc1).

Answer (score 43):

The solution is:

```
tesseract input.jpg stdout
```

But you need at least version 3.03